# Writing Type function in Python

Tags: python

I've been trying to write a function mytype(v) that performs the same action as type(), and can recognize integers, floats, strings, and lists. I was instructed to do this by first using str(v), and then reading the string. I'm almost done but when I input a set into mytype, i.e. mytype({1,2}), I'm required to make the function recognize it as a string but it keeps saying that it is a list. I was wondering how to fix my code so that the function recognizes sets as string, not a list. Here is what I have so far:

```
def mytype(v):

 s = str(v)

    import re

    # Check if list
    if re.search(r'[\[\]]', s):
        return "<type 'list'>"

    # Check if float
    if re.search(r'[\d]+\.', s): 
        return "<type 'float'>"

    # Check if int
    if re.search(r'[\d]+', s):
        return "<type 'int'>"

    # anything that's not an int, float or list
    return "<type 'string'>"
```

Comment: Hint: Have you checked what `str({1,2})` returns?

Comment: @Selcuk it returns 'set[1,2]'

Comment: @Selcuk would adding this as a first if statement solve the problem?                                                                                            
   if re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+', s):
        return "<type 'string'>"

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions are *too* generic.

For instance, `r'[\[\]]'` will actually match *everything* that contains a `[` or `]`, so the following input is a match: `'foobar[barfoo'`

You should make use of [anchors](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html):

```py
def mytype(v):

    s = str(v)

    import re

    # Check if list
    if re.search(r'^\[.*\]$', s):
        return "<type 'list'>"

    # Check if float
    if re.search(r'^\d+\.\d+$', s): 
        return "<type 'float'>"

    # Check if int
    if re.search(r'^\d+$', s):
        return "<type 'int'>"

    # anything that's not an int, float or list
    return "<type 'string'>"
```

A couple of tests:

```py
> mytype([])
"<type 'list'>"

> mytype(['a', 'b', 3])
"<type 'list'>"

> mytype(1.0)
"<type 'float'>"

> mtype(1.)
"<type 'float'>"

> mytype(123)
"<type 'int'>"

> mytype({1,2})
"<type 'string'>"

> mytype({'foo': 'bar'})
"<type 'string'>"
```

Comment: If you're going to anchor your search on both ends, using `search` or `match` doesn't really matter. (`fullmatch` would be another option, but it sounds like the questioner is on Python 2, which doesn't have that.)

Comment: @user2357112 That's true! I'll update the answer, thanks!